# How to stream 2 Lists & modify values in 1

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

I would like to iterate over 2 lists to update values in 1. Following is a simplified version of what I am trying to do using nested for loops.

The commented out code is as far as I got trying to utilize streams. Assume that last name is unique. The values I will be comparing in the actual code will in fact be unique.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

```
List<Person> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Person> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

list1.add(new Person("Jane", "Doe"));
list1.add(new Person("John", "Smith"));

list2.add(new Person("", "Doe"));
list2.add(new Person("", "Smith"));

for (Person p1 : list1) {
    for (Person p2 : list2) {
        if (p1.getLastName().equals(p2.getLastName())) {
            p2.setFirstName(p1.getFirstName());
            break;
        }
    }
}

System.out.println(list2.toString());

//list1.stream()
//  .filter(e -> (list2.stream()
//          .filter(d -> d.getLastName()
//          .equals(e.getLastName()))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classic `for` loops seems to be the best option. The `Stream` solution  could be as follows:

```
list1.forEach(p1 ->
    list2.stream().filter(p2 -> p1.getLastName().equals(p2.getLastName()))
                  .findFirst()
                  .ifPresent(p2 -> p2.setFirstName(p1.getFirstName())));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `<lastName, firstName>` map and use it to update the second list:

```
Map<String, String> lastNameMap = list1.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getLastName, Person::getFirstName));
list2.stream().forEach(p -> p.setFirstName(lastNameMap.get(p.getLastName())));
```

Note that this assumes that there are no duplicate last names, any duplicate last name may cause confusion.

As the `collect` call is written above, it will fail on duplicate `lastName` values, and maybe that should be kept as is so that an error can prevent last name/first name mix up.

Comment: You might have to check if the `lastNameMap` contains the lastName we are looking for

Comment: @user7 Good point. I chose to let the code set `firstName` to `null` if last name value isn't found in map... Or to leave it unchanged, that lambda can be changed to `p -> p.setLastName(lastNameMap.getOrDefault(p, ""))`

Comment: Well, if we need to go with the existing OP's behavior, then the current value must be unaffected (neither null or "") since the OP said the last names will be unique but I don't see any evidence that the list entries are 1-1. +1 anyway

Comment: @user7 Agreed. But between looking up the map twice just to filter and setting first name to its default value (which is `""` as per the question), I'd choose the latter, although I do see your point.

Answer (score 1):

Here another way to go about it:

```
 list1.forEach(p1 -> list2.stream()
                          .filter(p2 -> p1.getLastName().equals(p2.getLastName()))
                          .findFirst()
                          .ifPresent(p2 -> p2.setFirstName(p1.getFirstName()))
              );
```

or:

```
 list1.forEach(p1 -> list2.stream()
                          .filter(p2 -> p1.getLastName().equals(p2.getLastName()))
                          .limit(1)
                          .forEach(p2 -> p2.setFirstName(p1.getFirstName()))
              );
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want to solve your problem with streams I suppose you want to dive into functional programming. If that is the case I'd suggest you take a step back and try to internalize the basic principles of functional programming, so you can begin to approach a problem like this with a functional programming *mindset*. In this specific case that means: don't update your data structure(s) *in place*, but return a new instance with updated values instead (holding true for both your list and your person entity) and avoid running side-effectful blocks of code. Always return a meaningful value from an operation.

Considering this I'd suggest the following approach:

```
final List<Person> combined = list1.stream()
  .flatMap(p1 -> list2.stream().filter(p2 -> p2.lastname().equals(p1.lastName())).map(p2 -> new Person(p1.firstName(), p2.lastName())))
  .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Maybe you can take this as a starting point.

Comment: I am looping through 2 disparate objects. The Person object was used for simplification. If functional programming requires the creation of new objects then a classic for loop will suffice.

Comment: @BryanJ I'd suggest not using streams and especially lambdas then as that (misleadingly) indicates you are working with pure functions when you are not. This is more about style/convention though